# GraphicsMagick "gm identify" takes a long time for PDF

Tags: linux, pdf, imagemagick, graphicsmagick

I am trying to convert a PDF to a JPG preview, but certain PDF files are taking a really long time to process on our RH Linux server (+- 35 seconds). The same file & command on my Windows 8 development machine takes only 3 seconds. I am using GraphicsMagick 1.3.18 & GhostScript 8.70-19. I get the same results using ImageMagick. Unfortunately I can't share the PDF file in question, but here are its properties (it is only 399KB compressed & 1.1MB uncompressed):

[image: Adobe reader properties]

I tested using a compressed & uncompressed version, and the results are similar. I found that both the `gm convert file.pdf output.jpg` and `gm identify file.pdf` commands take a long time.

This is the output of `gm identify -version` on the Linux server:

```
GraphicsMagick 1.3.18 2013-03-10 Q8 http://www.GraphicsMagick.org/
Copyright (C) 2002-2013 GraphicsMagick Group.
Additional copyrights and licenses apply to this software.
See http://www.GraphicsMagick.org/www/Copyright.html for details.

Feature Support:
  Thread Safe              yes
  Large Files (> 32 bit)   yes
  Large Memory (> 32 bit)  yes
  BZIP                     yes
  DPS                      no
  FlashPix                 no
  FreeType                 yes
  Ghostscript (Library)    no
  JBIG                     no
  JPEG-2000                yes
  JPEG                     yes
  Little CMS               yes
  Loadable Modules         yes
  OpenMP                   yes (200805)
  PNG                      yes
  TIFF                     yes
  TRIO                     no
  UMEM                     no
  WMF                      yes
  X11                      yes
  XML                      yes
  ZLIB                     yes

Host type: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu

Configured using the command:
  ./configure  '--build=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--host=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--target=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--program-prefix=' '--prefix=/usr' '--exec-prefix=/usr' '--bindir=/usr/bin' '--sbindir=/usr/sbin' '--sysconfdir=/etc' '--datadir=/usr/share' '--includedir=/usr/include' '--libdir=/usr/lib64' '--libexecdir=/usr/libexec' '--localstatedir=/var' '--sharedstatedir=/var/lib' '--mandir=/usr/share/man' '--infodir=/usr/share/info' '--enable-shared' '--disable-static' '--with-lcms' '--with-magick_plus_plus' '--with-modules' '--with-perl' '--with-perl-options=INSTALLDIRS=vendor ' '--with-threads' '--with-wmf' '--with-x' '--with-xml' '--without-dps' '--without-gslib' '--with-gs-font-dir=/usr/share/fonts/default/Type1' 'build_alias=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' 'host_alias=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' 'target_alias=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' 'CFLAGS=-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic' 'CXXFLAGS=-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=

Final Build Parameters:
  CC       = gcc -std=gnu99
  CFLAGS   = -fopenmp -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -Wall -pthread
  CPPFLAGS = -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libxml2
  CXX      = g++
  CXXFLAGS = -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -pthread
  LDFLAGS  = -L/usr/lib -L/usr/lib
  LIBS     = -llcms -lfreetype -lXext -lSM -lICE -lX11 -lbz2 -lz -lltdl -lm -lgomp -lpthread
```

I only have this problem for some PDF files, most are processed using the same command quite quickly.

Any ideas regarding what might make this take so long?

Comment: What are the dimensions and resolution of the image?

Comment: "gm identify <filename>" takes 30 seconds and returns: <filename> PDF 595x842+0+0 DirectClass 8-bit 1.4M 0.000u 0:01